# Stuck on triangle geometry problem

Tags: geometry

[image: trianglegeometry]

The answer is $378$ but I can't seem to get it. I know that the triangles are similar, but I can't get past that. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Lengths are scaled  by a factor of $3$. So area is scaled by a factor of ???

Answer (score 0):

Since $AB=BC=CD$, $AD=3\times CD$. Because the triangles are similar, every side must be $3$ times as big. The area of the upper triangle is $42 = \frac{CE\times ED}{2}$, the area of the bigger triangle is given by $A = \frac{3CE \times 3ED}{2}$, or $9$ times that of the smaller triangle, so $A = 378$